# How to increase the height, programmatically, of a UIScrollView that has constrains?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, constraints

I am new in this world of iOS apps and i am developing an app that needs to show a detail information of an item. This detail can receive comments from the users and what i need is that every time the detail gets a new comment the height of my screen increase, here what I have done, this is the screen:

[image: I need to load the comments below the title]

[image: These are how my elements are]

The constrains for the Scroll are : **Trailing, Leading, top and bottom to its superview.**
For the View content: **Trailing, Leading, top, and bottom to its superview, Align center in x and y and equals height and width to the superview.**

All the comments come from a service, I want the content increase. I show all the comments but the UIScrollView doesn't work. I think is because of the constrains

Here is how i load and print the comments and change the contentzise of my scrollview:

```
    int y  = bottomLine.frame.origin.y + 8;
    int numComments = [[content objectForKey:@"comments"] intValue];

    if (numComments > 0) {
        for (int j=0; j < [comments count]; j++) {

                commentData = [comments objectAtIndex:j];

                //Create all the elements
                viewComments = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, y, self.view.bounds.size.width - 16, 109)];
                viewComments.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

                UIImageView *viewImgComment = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 50, 50)];

                NSURL *linckImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[commentData objectForKey:@"image"]];
                [viewImgComment sd_setImageWithURL:linckImage placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"place_holder_user"]];
                viewImgComment.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
                viewImgComment.clipsToBounds = YES;

                UILabel *lblTituloComment = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50 + 16, 8, (viewComments.bounds.size.width - 74) , 17)];
                [lblTituloComment setText:[commentData objectForKey:@"name"]];
                [lblTituloComment setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];

                UIView *viewRating = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50 + 16, 17 + 16, 121, 23)];
                viewRating.backgroundColor =[UIColor blackColor];
                viewRating.layer.cornerRadius = 11;

                UILabel *lblDescripcionComment = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 50 + 8, (viewComments.bounds.size.width - 16), 43)];

                [lblDescripcionComment setText:[commentData objectForKey:@"comment"]];
                [lblDescripcionComment setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
                [lblDescripcionComment setNumberOfLines:0];

                y = y + 117;

                [viewComments addSubview:viewImgComment];
                [viewComments addSubview:lblTituloComment];
                [viewComments addSubview:viewRating];
                [viewComments addSubview:lblDescripcionComment];

                [masterScroll addSubview:viewComments];
            }
        }
        //Increase the content size
        masterScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, y);
```

I hope some body can help me, I been trying for 3 days, researching and asking. Any question or any explanation of something let me know.

Comment: can you tell me, for comments are you using table view or uiview? if table view no issue. if you are using uiview then you have do some changes. Not big issue. Just tell me.

Comment: sure, I am using uiview.

Comment: 1. Keep record of Current height before adding comment.After adding comment ,calculate the height that view. Find difference between previous and current height.   2. Go to story board ->select height constraint of scroll view -> create a outlet for that constraint . ->  Now go to code -> heghtConstraint.constant = differenceHeight+currentHeightOfScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get your label heights (with contents text of label).

```
- (CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(UILabel*)label
{
    //Here label is your Comment label.
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize size;

    NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    CGSize boundingBox = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                                  context:context].size;

    size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));
    return size.height;
}
```

Get your comment label height and set scrollview content size:

```
CGSize *size;
CGFloat height =  [self getLabelHeight:lblDescripcionComment];
NSLog(@"totalHeight :%f",[self getLabelHeight:lblDescripcionComment]);
lblDescripcionComment.frame = CGRectMake(18, 260, 220, height);

#Here h is your scrollview height without comment label.
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,h+height)];
```